# How to set OJDBC version in PL SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, ojdbc

When I run the following code on my server in "Oracle SQL Developer" it runs correctly and dumps the table data to the output:

```
declare
rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for select * from LOCATION where rownum < 10;
    dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
end;
```

But when I run same code in "PL/SQL Developer" on the client side I get the following error:

> ORA-29481: Implicit results cannot be returned to client. ORA-06512:
>   at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2832 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2826
>   ORA-06512: at line 5
>
> View program sources of error stack?

I know that it is because of OJDBC driver on the client side so I have installed the latest OJDBC driver (12c) on the client side but still get that error message.

It seems that "PL/SQL Developer" still uses the old OJDBC driver.

I went through all of the "PL/SQL Developer" settings and couldn't see anything relevant to this. Also there is no way to define it in the connection or TNS definition.

Do you have any idea how can I tell "PL SQL developer" to use the JDBC driver version 12c?

Comment: PL/SQL Developer does not use Java, so it doesn't use the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about allroundautomations PL/SQL Developer than it has nothing to do with jdbc, as forum stands:
http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=53031

However maybe you can chose different OCI library in Preferences --> Connections -->OCI Library.

Your code works with at least PL/Sql Developer 10 with oracle 12 oci.dll.
This option is available from version 8

This screen is from Pl/Sql Developer 12 demo with 12.1 oci.dll with oracle 12.2 db. Implicit statement result is available from 12.1 I believe.

[image]